# How to implement SharedPreferences to preserve Integer between sessions?

Tags: java, android

My app was running fine, except that after closing and reopening the app, the maximum score (maxwhacks) was showing as "0" (i.e.: it was not kept between sessions). I was trying to fix this bug with SharedPreferences, but now my app crashes when I open it. Can you find what is wrong in the app? The two methods I was trying to implement are: setBestScore and getBestScore.

The parts I added:

```
int previousMaxScore = getBestScore();

maxwhacks = previousMaxScore;

TextView maxWhacksStored = findViewById(R.id.numberOfMaxWhacksView);
maxWhacksStored.setText(previousMaxScore);
```

```
setBestScore(maxwhacks);
```

```
public void setBestScore(int bestScore) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("gamepanel", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putInt("bestScore", maxwhacks);
        editor.apply();
    }

public int getBestScore() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("gamepanel", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getInt("bestScore", 0);
    }
```

Full code:

Java:

```
package com.example.android.whack_a_lock_022;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity<sharedPreferences, maxwhacks> extends AppCompatActivity {

    public CountDownTimer countDownTimer = null;
    int cl = 0;
    int nl = 0;
    int sl = 0;
    int whacks = 0;
    int maxwhacks = 0;
    float random0to1;
    Random r;
    private Button start;
    private Button cancel;
    private TextView time;
    TextView maxWhacksStored;
    private SharedPreferences myPrefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        maxwhacks = getBestScore();

        TextView maxWhacksStored = findViewById(R.id.numberOfMaxWhacksView);
        maxWhacksStored.setText(maxwhacks);

        r = new Random();

        Button clButton = findViewById(R.id.cl);
        Button nlButton = findViewById(R.id.nl);
        Button slButton = findViewById(R.id.sl);

        View.OnClickListener btnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.startButton:
                        start();
                        break;
                    case R.id.cancelButton:
                        cancel();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        clButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cl == 1) {
                    cl = 0;
                    TextView CapsLock = findViewById(R.id.cl);
                    CapsLock.setText("caps lock");
                    whacks++;
                    TextView NumberOfWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfWhacksView);
                    NumberOfWhacks.setText(String.valueOf(whacks));
                    if (whacks > maxwhacks) {
                        maxwhacks = whacks;
                        TextView NumberOfMaxWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfMaxWhacksView);
                        NumberOfMaxWhacks.setText(String.valueOf(maxwhacks));
                    }

                    pop();
                }
            }
        });

        nlButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (nl == 1) {
                    nl = 0;
                    TextView NumLock = findViewById(R.id.nl);
                    NumLock.setText("num lk");
                    whacks++;
                    TextView NumberOfWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfWhacksView);
                    NumberOfWhacks.setText(String.valueOf(whacks));
                    if (whacks > maxwhacks) {
                        maxwhacks = whacks;
                        TextView NumberOfMaxWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfMaxWhacksView);
                        NumberOfMaxWhacks.setText(String.valueOf(maxwhacks));
                    }

                    pop();
                }
            }
        });

        slButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (sl == 1) {
                    sl = 0;
                    TextView ScrollLock = findViewById(R.id.sl);
                    ScrollLock.setText("scr lk");
                    whacks++;
                    TextView NumberOfWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfWhacksView);
                    NumberOfWhacks.setText(String.valueOf(whacks));
                    if (whacks > maxwhacks) {
                        maxwhacks = whacks;
                        TextView NumberOfMaxWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfMaxWhacksView);
                        NumberOfMaxWhacks.setText(String.valueOf(maxwhacks));
                    }

                    pop();
                }
            }
        });

        // Capture our button from layout
        start = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        start.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        cancel = findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        time = findViewById(R.id.time);

        // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above

    }

    public float numAlea() {
        return r.nextFloat();
    }

    private void start() {
        if (countDownTimer == null) {
            time.setText("60");

            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    time.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    cl = 0;
                    nl = 0;
                    sl = 0;
                    whacks = 0;
                    TextView CapsLock = findViewById(R.id.cl);
                    CapsLock.setText("caps lock");
                    TextView NumLock = findViewById(R.id.nl);
                    NumLock.setText("num lk");
                    TextView ScrollLock = findViewById(R.id.sl);
                    ScrollLock.setText("scr lk");
                    countDownTimer = null;
                    time.setText("Done !");

                    setBestScore(maxwhacks);

                }
            };
            countDownTimer.start();

            pop();
        }
    }

    private void pop() {
        // Escolhe e "POPa" o botão

        // Gera número aleatório

        random0to1 = numAlea();

        if (random0to1 <= (1F / 3)) {

            cl = 1;
            Button clButton = findViewById(R.id.cl);
            clButton.setText("CAPS LOCK");

        } else if (random0to1 <= 2F / 3) {
            nl = 1;
            Button nlButton = findViewById(R.id.nl);
            nlButton.setText("NUM LK");
        } else if (random0to1 <= 1F) {
            sl = 1;
            Button slButton = findViewById(R.id.sl);
            slButton.setText("SCR LK");
        }
    }

    private void cancel() {
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;
        }

        //Põe botões a zeros

        cl = 0;
        Button clButton = findViewById(R.id.cl);
        clButton.setText("caps lock");

        nl = 0;
        Button nlButton = findViewById(R.id.nl);
        nlButton.setText("num lk");

        sl = 0;
        Button slButton = findViewById(R.id.sl);
        slButton.setText("scr lk");

        whacks = 0;
        TextView NumberOfWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfWhacksView);
        NumberOfWhacks.setText("0");

    }
    public void setBestScore(int bestScore) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("gamepanel", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putInt("bestScore", maxwhacks);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public int getBestScore() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("gamepanel", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getInt("bestScore", 0);
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/whacksView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="WHACKS"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/maxWhacksView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="MAX WHACKS"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="60"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberOfWhacksView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberOfMaxWhacksView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="caps lock"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAllCaps = "false"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="num lk"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAllCaps = "false"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="scr lk"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAllCaps = "false"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please add crash report

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the crash report to know exactly what is wrong, at the start you need to set a `String` to the `TextView` text not an int

change

```
maxWhacksStored.setText(previousMaxScore);
```

to

```
maxWhacksStored.setText(String.valueOf(previousMaxScore));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have post crash report too,

From coding i can say that,

u can not pass direct integer value into setText().

easiest way to resolve this you can change from

> maxWhacksStored.setText(previousMaxScore);

to

> maxWhacksStored.setText(""+previousMaxScore);